# What's the difference between {"::"} and "::"?

Tags: c#

I have some code like this:

```
 string[] separator = {"::"};
 var seperatedCardString = currentCard.Name.Split(
    separator, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

Can someone explain to me exactly what's happening with this and why there is a need to use {"::"}.  My separator is :: so I am confused as to why it's coded the way it is.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The code line `string[] separator = {"::"};` is initializing array `separator`. This syntax to initialize the array is referred as [Implicitly Typed Arrays](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/arrays/implicitly-typed-arrays).

Currently your code using `Split(String[], StringSplitOptions)` method of string to split the string where the first arg is type of string array. If you have only one seperator (i.e. `::`) then you can use the overload method `Split(String, StringSplitOptions)` by below code

```
 string separator = "::";
 var seperatedCardString = currentCard.Name.Split(
    separator, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

Check all the overload of string `Split` method at [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.split?view=net-5.0)